# KQL How to format a time duration

Tags: elasticsearch, kql

Using KQL within ElasticSearch.
I have a start date and and end date which I want to find the call duration and display it in the format of hh:mm:ss
Here is my formula:

```
(last_value(endtime, kql='endtime: *') - last_value(starttime, kql='starttime: *')) / 60000
```

The result shown using the formula above is:
[Call Duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDuM5.png)

I believe I need to use format_timespan but unsure how to do this.

Thanks.

Tried using the format_timespan at various points in the formula

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always make sure to use the right language tags for your question.